# Data doesn't update when doing fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next.js14

I am creating a nexjs program that takes data every 5 minutes from an API, and displays it on screen.

The problem is that today in the morning I did the test of the code and it was left with that data. Even if I restart the server or reload the page, the data is still there.

```
import React from 'react';

export default async function Page() {
  const res = await fetch('MY API');
  const data = await res.json();

  // Extraer datos específicos
  const instrumentID = data[0]?.instrumentID || '';
  const location = data[0]?.location || '';
  const utc = data[0]?.utc || '';
  const timestamp = data[0]?.timestamp || '';
  const weight = data[0]?.data.filter(item => item.unit === 'Tons') || [];
  const temperature = data[0]?.data.find(item => item.name === 'Temperature') || {};
  const humidity = data[0]?.data.find(item => item.name === 'Humidity') || {};
  const windSpeed = data[0]?.data.find(item => item.name === 'Wind Speed') || {};
  const windDirection = data[0]?.data.find(item => item.name === 'Wind Direction') || {};


  return (
    <div className="col">
      <div>Instrument ID: {instrumentID}</div>
      <div>Location: {location}</div>
      <div>Hora: {utc}</div>
      <div>Timestamp: {timestamp}</div>

      <div>
        <h2>Weight:</h2>
        {weight.map(item => (
          <div key={item.name}>
            <div>{item.name}: {item.value} {item.unit}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Temperature:</h2>
        <div>{temperature.name}: {temperature.value} {temperature.unit}</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Humidity:</h2>
        <div>{humidity.name}: {humidity.value} {humidity.unit}</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>Wind:</h2>
        <div>{windSpeed.name}: {windSpeed.value} {windSpeed.unit}</div>
        <div>{windDirection.name}: {windDirection.value} {windDirection.unit}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the data structure got in postman

```json
[
    {
        "utc": "2024-01-07T21:00:00.000+00:00",
        "timestamp": "2024-01-07T18:00:00.000+00:00",
        "instrumentID": "XXX",
        "location": "Space",
        "gpsCoordinates": "123,911",
        "data": [
            {
                "unit": "Tons",
                "name": "Weight",
                "value": "5.9"
            },
            {
                "unit": "Celsius",
                "name": "Temperature",
                "value": "21.4"
            },
            {
                "unit": "% RH",
                "name": "Humidity",
                "value": "87.6"
            },
            {
                "unit": "mtr/sec",
                "name": "Wind Speed",
                "value": "0.5"
            },
            {
                "unit": "degrees",
                "name": "Wind Direction",
                "value": "25.0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: The code you currently show, will display what it receives from the API. So either the API doesn't deliver updated data, or the request isn't done periodically. Have you tried debugging? Is the request issued correctly in the said interval? If yes, is the request successful? Have you debugged your `Page()` funciton, that the data is correctly received? Has the data that is received changed? Maybe the browser or the backend is caching the fetch results?

Comment: `fetch` api  in next.js13 caches request by default.

Comment: Does this happen building the application or when developing it? It could be a caching issue. The `fetch` function in Next takes additional options that can be modified. If you pass `{ next: { revalidate: 0 } }` as an option for `fetch(url, options)` then you can tell Next to always use fresh data from your API. (More info: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data)

Comment: Thanks, it worked to me { next: { revalidate: 0 } }